# html code wont show up after loading a html page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

EDIT: How can I extend/edit "appended content" ? 
I mean, If I have a div named "website" at "include.html" (the file which I appended using jquerys load) , Can I add text / code to that DIV after appending it?

I have a simple HTML menu page which Im trying to load to every page in my website.
Sorry if its a noob question ;) kinda noob with Jquery/js/html.

Here's one of the files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cstyles.css">
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='menu2.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='menu_load.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            loadContent();
            $(document).on('mouseenter', "#menulist", function() {
                mainmenu();
            });
        </script>
        <div id="contact_us" style="background:blue;">Something</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Heres menu2.js:

```
function mainmenu() {
    $(" #menulist li").hover(function () {
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({
            visibility: "visible",
            display: "none"
        }).show(300);
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({
            visibility: "hidden"
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    mainmenu();
});
```

heres menu_load.js:

```
function loadContent() {
    $("body").load("include.html");
}
```

Problem is: After loading the menu successfully (the html file named INCLUDE.html), The content on the page "disappears"...

In this case, the word: something wont show up. 
To be more clear, it will show up for a second and then will be replaced by the content on the "include.html" file.

Any suggestions?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You are loading the file into the documents body, so it will replace its content completely. This is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the way `$("#body").load()` works. I would suggest changing that with

```
.prepend()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're loading the `include.html` file in the entire document. You should make a  element with an id and load it there. For example

```
<div id="toload"></div>
```

Then your jquery function would be:

```
function loadContent() {
$("#toload").load("include.html");
}
```